# Difficulty with gcloud run service - migrating to espV2

Tags: web-services, gcloud, google-cloud-endpoints

Ive been following the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run#configure_esp)

I am able to load an image (Hello example), create endpoints, and run it as a service.....however, whenever I follow the process to migrate the working services to ESPv2, I get the following:

{"message":"upstream request timeout","code":504}

I've tried this on two different services.    Any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Please add a little more detail explaining what you've done and what you do to lead you to the error.  Deploying Cloud Endpoints is **not** trivial but it is straightforward; as long as you follow the steps exactly as documented, it works. I've deployed Cloud Endpoints and Cloud Run several times and I know the instructions work but you can't afford to miss a step or make any (even minor) mistakes, unfortunately. I blogged about my experience and these instructions should still be good with one exception that the generated ESPv2 (container) image now includes a version number.

Comment: See: https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/200325/

Comment: I have been able to take the demo image for test and deploy it.    I was successful in creating and deploying the endpoints from the openAPI-run.yaml file.      I could run the service with Curl without any issues.   I have downloaded the script (gcloud_build_image) and run it without errors.....chmod +x gcloud_build_image
  
./gcloud_build_image -s hello-ef4dv4yxsq-uc.a.run.app \                                     
    -c 2021-06-01r4 -p document-tools

Comment: I can then deploy without errors....gcloud run deploy hello \                              
  --image="gcr.io/document-tools/endpoints-runtime-serverless:2.26.1-hello-ef4dv4yxsq-uc.a.run.app-2021-06-01r4" \
  --allow-unauthenticated \                                                     
  --platform managed \
  --project=document-tools

Comment: I then try to run the curl command and I'm getting 504 timeout errors.                                                                                                                               
   curl --request GET \                                   
   --header "content-type:application/json" \
   "https://hello-ef4dv4yxsq-uc.a.run.app/hello"

Comment: That you can curl the `hello` service directly and you don't get errors deploying the proxy, the 504 suggests that the proxy isn't communicating correctly with the backend `hello` service. Please add your OpenAPI config to your question. I've done the gRPC but not the REST deployment. I may be able to grab some time later today to try the REST run-through if you're still having problems

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.   I was not aware that ESPv2 is only a proxy that needs to co-exist and point to the original backend service.

As soon as I created a separate service, everything worked.